# error undefined method in method call by pressing bootstrap button on index page Rails 4

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, typhoeus

I need to call method download_images("\folder","http:\url") which save pictures from url in choosen directory.This method should be called in index.html.erb and grab folder address from textbox1 and url from textbox2 after pressing the button1.

---

Right now I don't know how to grab strings from textboxes, I am trying to call method correctlyThe index.html.erb code:

```html
<h1>Welcome#index</h1>

<p><%=  "Download pictures from url!" %></p>
   
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <p> Input url: </p>
  <p> <input type="text"/> </p>
  <p> Input destination folder: </p>
  <p> <input type="text"/> </p>
    <button class="btn">Go!</button>
  <% button_to "btn", :method=> download_images("`/tutorial1/downloadedpics","http://www.yandex.ru/") %>
</div>
```

---

I defined method download_images in welcome_controller.rb:

```html
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def download_images(url, destination_path, options = {})
    base_url = URI.join(url, "/").to_s
    body = Typhoeus::Request.get(url).body
    imgs = Nokogiri::HTML(body).css("img")
    image_srcs = imgs.map { |img| img["src"] }.compact.uniq

    hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => options[:max_concurrency] || 50)
    image_paths = image_srcs.map do |image_src|
      image_url = URI.join(base_url, image_src).to_s
      path = File.join(destination_path, File.basename(image_url))
      request = Typhoeus::Request.new(image_url)
      request.on_complete { |response| File.write(path, response.body) }
      hydra.queue(request)
      path
    end
    hydra.run
    image_paths
  end

  
end
```

After I switch server and go to localhost, I receive an exception:
 NoMethodError in Welcome#index, undefined method `download_images' for #<#<Class:0x007f202fc3ae50>:0x007f202f9ab518>, in line  <% button_to "btn", :method=> download_images("`/tutorial1/downloadedpics","http://www.yandex.ru/") %>

I am a noob programmer, so I can do rather dumb mistakes...
And it is important to mention: I work in Nitrous web box, and don't really know is it possible to download images in box folder:

> ~/tutorial1/downloadedpics

Also      I use Bootstrap controllers,Nokogiri gem and Typhoeus gem.
Ruby version:ruby 2.1.1p76
Rails version:Rails 4.1.0 
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

As a FYI, doing:

```
imgs = Nokogiri::HTML(body).css("img")
image_srcs = imgs.map { |img| img["src"] }.compact.uniq
```

is not the right way to find images with "src" parameters. Because you're not searching correctly, you get nils in your resulting array, forcing you to use `compact`. Instead, don't rely on cleaning up after making a mess, just avoid making the mess in the first place:

```
require 'nokogiri'

body = <<EOT
<html>
<body>
  <img>
  <img src="foo">
</body>
</html>
EOT

imgs = Nokogiri::HTML(body).css("img[@src]")
image_srcs = imgs.map { |img| img["src"] }
image_srcs # => ["foo"]
```